# How do I search for certain IDs in a page and match them to variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a collection of strings which I want to select from to insert text into a page.

The strings are stored in an object/array, like so:

```
var strings = {
    x01: 'Hello world',
    x02: 'Goodbye world'
    x03: 'The quick brown fox',
    x04: 'jumped over'
    x05: 'the lazy dog',
    x06: 'the fat lady sung'
};
```

In my HTML, I have span tags that have IDs that correspond to the variables above.

However, on any one page, only some of the spans will show up at any one time. So, for example, there might be only three of them:

```
<span id="x01"></span>
<span id="x04"></span>
<span id="x06"></span>
```

What I want to do is be able to search the page to gather up all the IDs that match the naming convention (x followed by two digits), and then match them to the corresponding variable so that I can fill the span with the appropriate text.

Something like (this is a rough outline, not meant to be taken as actual code):

```
array = getElementsByID(someKindOfMultipleSelect);
for (var key in array)
{
   document.getElementById(**IDandVarName**).innerHTML = strings.**IDandVarName**;
}
```

Despite doing some Googling on this, I'm stuck on two points. I don't know how to gather the span IDs I want from the page, and I don't quite know how to match them up once I've got them.

Yes, I'm kind of a noob at Javascript, so please be gentle with me in explaining this.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a pure (and very simple) JavaScript solution. This solution avoids gathering up all the spans on the page (not efficient), and grabs the elements by ID only.

**HTML:**

```
<span id="x01"></span>
<span id="x04"></span>
<span id="x06"></span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var strings = {
    x01: 'Hello world',
    x02: 'Goodbye world',
    x03: 'The quick brown fox',
    x04: 'jumped over',
    x05: 'the lazy dog',
    x06: 'the fat lady sung'
};

for (var key in strings) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(key);

    if(obj)
        document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = strings[key];
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/q9Gmf/).

Comment: That really is a great deal more graceful and performant than my attempt; +1 =)

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there. Instead of trying to gather the spans first and seeing if they match, you walk through the string variables and match that way round. Cool... but lets say I had 1000 strings (I don't, but if I did...). Would that be a hit on the CPU? Or would it be insignificant?

Comment: @DaveMG, Only testing can really answer that question. Here's the bottom line if you *need* to do what you're attempting: If you have 200 strings, and (possibly) 200 ID's to match them to, it doesn't really matter how long it takes. If you need to do it, you need to do it. http://jsperf.com/ is a great site that will allow you to test multiple ways of accomplishing your goal and give you a performance report for each. Although I haven't tested any other ways, I can't think of a more efficient way than what I've posted.

Comment: I guess I only asked because the number of spans on the page are almost certainly always going to be a tenth or so of the number of available strings. That's why I was originally thinking of trying to get the spans first, because then I'd be walking the array an average of 20 times instead of always 200. Still... your way works, and I'm a big fan of getting solutions that work first, and optimizing later. So cheers for the code!

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
$('span[id^="x"]').each( // selects all span elements whose id starts with an x
    function(i){
        $(this).text(strings[this.id]);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4tSaL/).

---

**Edited** to add a plain JavaScript solution (I couldn't *sworn* I saw a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) originally...sigh):

```
var elems = 'span';

var spans = document.getElementsByTagName(elems);

for (i=0; i<spans.length; i++){
    if (strings[spans[i].id]){
        spans[i].innerHTML = strings[spans[i].id];
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4tSaL/1/).

References:

- [attribute-starts-with (`^=`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Isn't looping over the elements unnecessarily slow and complicated? Or is there an advantage I don't see over looping over the data?

Comment: @RoToRa: no, you're absolutely right mine is the slower approach; but by the time I'd realised that this question wasn't tagged with jQuery and edited in the current vanilla JS [James Hill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673678/how-do-i-search-for-certain-ids-in-a-page-and-match-them-to-variables-in-javascri/7673846#7673846) had already posted his version, which I couldn't really improve upon, and couldn't add anything to in order to improve my answer further. Also, see my comment to his answer. His is the better approach by far. =)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to "search" the document for your ID's. Your code is basicly allready correct, just leave out the first line and use the `key` variable of the loop:

```
for (var key in strings)
{
   document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = strings[key];
}
```

Hwoever this will break if an element with one of the IDs doesn't exist, so a check would be a good idea:

```
for (var key in strings)
{
   var element = document.getElementById(key);
   if (element)
       element.innerHTML = strings[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vCwuu/1/

So without using jquery you can do something like this

add a class to all elements that you can find them with

```
<span class="fill-me" id="x01"></span>
<span class="fill-me" id="x04"></span>
<span class="fill-me" id="x06"></span>
```

and find them and look upp there corresponding text

```
var strings = {
 x01: 'Hello world',
 x02: 'Goodbye world',
 x03: 'The quick brown fox',
 x04: 'jumped over',
 x05: 'the lazy dog',
 x06: 'the fat lady sung'
};

window.onload = function() {
 console.log("sup");
 var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("fill-me");
 for(i in spans) {
  spans[i].innerHTML = strings[spans[i].id];   
 }
};
```

Comment: I think this is an overly complicated solution. The ID's of the desired elements are stored in `strings`, there is no need to gather up all the elements by class name.

Comment: i ges the question is a bit context less but this style more fits the problems i generally face. But yea in your example you had all the ids of the elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to check if an element exists:

`if (document.getElementById('x01')) {
    // code
}`

If there are too many elements for that to be useful, you could give all the elements the same name like

```
<div id="x01" name="xx"></div>
<div id="x02" name="xx"></div>
```

Then use

```
arr = document.getElementsByName("xx");
```

To get all the divs on the page.